# Which indexes do I need to add to speed up this MYSQL JOIN/GROUP BY/HAVING query?

Tags: mysql, indexing

The following query takes about 30 seconds to execute when current_vacature_response contains 88k records, and daily_vacature_response contains 10k records. Using EXPLAIN I've concluded that no indexes where used from the `current_vacature_response` table. I've added some basic indexes, but none of them seem to be used. What kind of index do I need to set to speed up this query?

Query:

```
SELECT c.`stats_date` as `stats_date` 
    FROM `current_vacature_response` c 
    LEFT JOIN `daily_vacature_response` d ON (c.`stats_date` = d.`stats_date` )
    GROUP BY c.`stats_date`, d.`stats_date` 
    HAVING max(d.`last_stats_datetime`) IS NULL 
        OR MAX(d.`last_stats_datetime`) < MAX(c.`created_datetime`);
```

current_vacature_response table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `current_vacature_response` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `site_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `stats_date` date NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('typ1', 'type2') NOT NULL,
  `vacature` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `current_vacature_created_datetime` (`created_datetime`),
  KEY `current_vacature_response_vacature` (`vacature`),
  KEY `current_vacature_response_type` (`type`),
  KEY `current_vacature_stats_date` (`stats_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=88210 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

daily_vacature_response table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `daily_vacature_response` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contact` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `site_id` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `spotlight_result` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stats_date` date NOT NULL,
  `last_stats_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `vacature` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `daily_vacature_response_key` (`site_id`,`vacature`,`stats_date`),
  KEY `daily_vacature_response_last_stats_datetime` (`last_stats_datetime`),
  KEY `daily_vacature_response_stats_date` (`stats_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9802 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Explain output:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: c
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 88209
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: d
         type: ref
possible_keys: daily_vacature_response_stats_date
          key: daily_vacature_response_stats_date
      key_len: 3
          ref: reporting_development.c.stats_date
         rows: 99
        Extra:
```

Comment: You are filtering only in HAVING clause, which is performed after all other operations, so it's too late for it to use indexes. The best you can do is to rewrite a query in a way that the filtering is performed on an early stage (in a where clause, or in the join condition). Otherwise MySQL will always have to scan the entire current_vacature_response table. So the only solution would be to rewrite the query, but in order to do it correcly, please explain the stats_date, created_datetime, last_stats_datetime. Can you also provide some example input and expected output?

Comment: Tnx, I've rewritten it a much faster query (4ms): SELECT c.`stats_date` 
 FROM `current_cv_response` c 
 GROUP BY c.`stats_date`
 HAVING MAX(c.`created_datetime`) NOT IN 
 (SELECT MAX(d.`last_stats_datetime` ) 
  FROM `daily_cv_response` d 
  WHERE d.`stats_date` = c.`stats_date` 
  GROUP BY d.`stats_date`);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an index on `daily_vacature_response(stats_date, last_stats_datetime)`.

I'm suspicious that it'll make a huge difference, but that's the most likely candidate.

Also, try rewriting the query a little bit (might not work in MySQL, but worth trying):

```
GROUP BY c.`stats_date`, c.`created_datetime`, d.`stats_date` 
HAVING max(d.`last_stats_datetime`) IS NULL 
    OR max(d.`last_stats_datetime`) < c.`created_datetime`;
```